# Can’t open file by dynamic POST filename (some type) Groupdocs Annotation

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, groupdocs

**Groupdocs Annotation**

when default file powerpoint and exel show “Cannot open presentation.” Or “Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index” same image

But type .doc .png .jpg and whatever can open normal.
how fix open type .xlsx and .pptx

> code default my file name [#img1#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M38Lb.png) 
> .xlsx [#img2#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNzzJ.png) 
> .ppt [#img3#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3s54.png)
> .docx [#img4#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCQL6.png)

Comment: Please, explain your case with more details. Also, it will be much better if you place your code inside your question instead of link to it on an external website. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try opening in Read Only Mode.  Excel and Power Point often gives warning when attempting to open a file that is already opened by another user.  Read Only Mode will eliminate the warning.